# Overriding functions in wordpress plugins

Tags: plugins, pluggable

I notice that in some plugins you can override functions by ...

1. Creating an uploads folder
2. Creating a folder with the plugin name
3. Using the following code

   ```
   if (!function_exists('function_name')) {
       function function_name() {

       }
   }
   ```

Is this standard for all Wordpress plugins or only if they're written in a specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin displays content via any function, the code:

```
if(!function_exists('function_name')) function_name();
```

... is used for safety.

If your plugin is disabled, and the `if (!function_exists('function_name'))` is missing, your theme will throw a fatal error.

Comment: This isn't actually correct. The OP is referring to wrapping the *function definition* in a `if( ! function_exists() )` conditional, *not* the actual function call in the *template*.

Comment: Yes, but his wording is not the best. The wrapping is done for theme safety only, and not for overriding WordPress functions.

Answer (score 0):

These are referred to as *pluggable functions*, and are intended to be able to be over-ridden, either by Plugins, Themes, or Child Themes.

It is only standard for functions that are intended to be over-ridden - and, generally speaking, the better practice is to add filter hooks to function outputs, rather than making functions pluggable.